# looking for most efficient way to display JSON data received via websocket, into a Xcode/Swift dynamic table

Tags: json, swift, xcode, tableview

Currently I am working on a MacOS financial market trading application that could receive 10-20 websocket messages per second containing JSON data. For now, let's assume that once the data has been displayed in a table and a new message has been received, the previous data is no longer needed. What would be the recommended, and most efficient way to get the data into the table, and to keep updating it as fast as possible?

I have the websocket connection setup and working properly (using SocketRocket. Data is coming in as it should. But I really don't want to continue further without having a better understanding of the most efficient way to present that data into the table. I was reading about DictionaryArrayController, and maybe utilizing a database library, but I think the latter would would only add unnecessary overhead for what I am trying to do.

Below is a sample of the data that I am receiving.

```
    {
    "id":"5267",
    "pt":"T",
    "ls":["1"],
    "lp":["11968"],
    "t":["1571824228"],
    "v":"133758",
    "h":"11981",
    "l":"11928",
    "bp":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
    "bs":["14","73","87","66","74","96","98","85","111","104"],
    "ap":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"],
    "as":["69","67","62","124","89","105","97","107","113","124"]
    }
```

The only values that I will need to display & update to the table will be coming from keys:  "ls" "lp" "v" "h" "l" "bs" "as"

I don't really need a detailed coded response, but I'd never refuse it, either. Mainly just looking for thoughts so I don't have to switch to a different way, later.

I'll also attach an screen capture of an Excel file showing about how the cells will be laid out.  [screenshot of desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LXZM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a JSON decoder, built in to Swift?

Create an appropriate using model, using the Decodable protocol. The property names and data types must match the incoming JSON exactly

```
struct IncomingData: Decodable {
{
    let ls: [String],
    let lp: [String],
    let h: String,
    let as: [String]
}
```

The set up the parse like this:

```
func parseJSON(_ incomingData: Data) -> IncomingData? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let parsedData = try decoder.decode(IncomingData.self, from: incomingData)

        print("as: \(as)"
        return parsedData
    }
    catch {
        self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Michael, especially for taking the time to type that out!  I do have something similar as what you have mentioned, but using the swiftyJSON library.  the main thing that I'm trying to understand/find out, is the absolute fastest way to display the data that is being received via websockets, onto the screen, with the least amount of lag or delay.  even if the data will only be valid for .2 seconds.  in some cases it may be possible to just change the text of a label, or some views it may be necessary to display it into a tableview.

Comment: a long time ago, I did some programming with Visual Basic and it seemed that way back then, it was very easy to work with spreadsheet type tables in an app.  but this Xcode/Swift stuff seems a bit overwhelming with everything that's necessary to do, to accomplish what I need.  perhaps a 3rd party library for simple table views that would cutback on some of the work?  (similar to how swiftyJSON cutback on the work when dealing with JSON in earlier versions of Swift).